# BroadcastReceiver java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, classnotfoundexception

I try to show a simple toast message on phone startup.
I wasted almost a day trying to figure out why my code did not work.

Here is the full error:

```
Unable to instantiate receiver com.debug.receivebootcomplete.debug.BroadcastReceiverClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.debug.receivebootcomplete.debug.BroadcastReceiverClass
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.debug.receivebootcomplete.debug">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverClass" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And my class:

```
namespace Debug
{
    class BroadcastReceiverClass:BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText (context,"Work",ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }
    }
}
```

In emulator debug the application throw the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and on phone when reboot the application crash.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you working with `Xamarin` ?

Comment: Where are you calling this class? can we see the code for that?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13614/how-do-i-update-my-activity-using-a-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Talha!

My error was generated by the intent-filter tag. I have no idea why because in every topic that I saw everybody used that tag in Manifest file.

```
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
        </intent-filter>
```

So I remove it and add 
    
    `[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {Intent.ActionBootCompleted})]`

to the BroadcastReceiver class.